# Plot data as bar-candle-like chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataset with following structue:

```
[Title,Value_A,Value_B]
```

Some real world examples are:

```
[A,0.1,0.3]
[B,0.5,0.6]
[I,1,0.6]
[R,0.6,0.7]
```

I want a bar-like chart like this sketch:

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3flni.png)

I want to use matplotlib.pyplot lib, tried a lot but just need a hint.
Also,i am open for other libraries.

Edit1:
Sorry i was not precise enough. Data is stored in Pandas DataFrame

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame()
df["title"] = ("A","B","C","D")
df["value_1"] = (0.1,0.5,1,0.6)
df["value_2"] = (0.3,0.6,0.6,0.7)
df.plot(x="title", y="value_1", kind="bar",stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

This is what i got as simple start. My Problem is that i dont know how to feed the y axes with 2 values which are present as a bar/candle.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! How is your dataset stored? a list of lists? Or are you using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html)?

Comment: Thanks :) I edited the Question with more informations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [plt.bar](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html):

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(x=df['title'], 
       bottom=df['value_1'], 
       height=df['value_2'] - df['value_1'])

ax.set_ylim(bottom=0, top=1.2)
new_yticks = list(set(df['value_1']).union(df['value_2']))
plt.yticks(new_yticks)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot_result]

---

**Alternatively**
as @LuisAlejandro suggested, you can use [`ax.violinplot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.violinplot.html), but you have to extract the values from the dataframe first:

```py
vals = list(df[['value_1', 'value_2']].T.to_dict('list').values())
# [[0.1, 0.3], [0.5, 0.6], [1.0, 0.6], [0.6, 0.7]]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.violinplot(vals)

ax.set_ylim(bottom=0, top=1.2)
plt.yticks(new_yticks)
plt.show()
```

[image: violin-plot]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one is what you need:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

collectn_1 = [0.1,0.3]
collectn_2 = [0.5,0.6]
collectn_3 = [0.6,1]
collectn_4 = [0.6,0.7]

## combine these different collections into a list
data_to_plot = [collectn_1, collectn_2, collectn_3, collectn_4]

# Create a figure instance
fig = plt.figure()

# Create an axes instance
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])

# Create the boxplot
bp = ax.violinplot(data_to_plot)
plt.show()
```

Comment: yeah something like this (i edited my question with current code). i think i somehow make the y axes eat 2 instead of one value